# find . -type -exec fgrep problems

Tags: linux, shell, find, aix

I'm new to linux/aix. I'm working on aix and i have the following problem:

if i try a

```
find . -type f -exec fgrep -l 'searchword *$'
```

doesn't return nothing or is stuck.

I know that i have files with the searchword.

Does `fgrep -l` doesn't suport the `*$`?

To give a better explanation, i`m searching some logs on my computer for a 'searchword' which in front of it can have anything but i want it to finish with *word, and than grep that line.
Also i now that the line after *word has spaces or blank, thats why i put *$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need `{}` to complete your `fgrep` and you don't need wildcard in grep pattern:

```
 find . -type f -exec fgrep -l 'searchword' '{}' \;
```

Also note that you don;t really need find since modern grep support **recursive search** also.

Something like would also work:

```
grep -lr 'searchword' *
```

Comment: so for example if i have 2 logs like:
1log: xyz Job
      text text
2log  xyz Job_test
      text text
I used find to show me the logs that contains exactly only "xyz Job" in this case only 1log. But how can i say in grep word search that i want only this to be searched like "*Job" i thought that this will tell the grep "Job *$".
Thank you!

Comment: You can use this grep: `grep -ilr ' Job' *` `" job"` will find `space+Job` pattern

Comment: Thank works ok in linux! grep - ilr 'Job' *, but on AIX it fails "ksh: /usr/bin/grep: 0403-027 The parameter list is too long."

Comment: You might have too many files. Try: **`grep -ilr ' Job' .`** which will give same output.

Comment: Done it! thank you again to both of the answers which were great :)

Answer (score 1):

`fgrep` is used primarily for searching for *fixed* strings rather than regular expressions.

Just use `grep` or `egrep`, both of which cater for regular expressions.

In addition, you need to provide the file marker and terminator to the `-exec` flag:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l 'searchword *$' {} ';'
```